# Understanding the definition of semisimple Lie algebras in terms of ideals

Tags: definition, lie-algebras, ideals, semisimple-lie-algebras

I'm struggling to understand the definition of a semisimple Lie algebra. The definitions I'm using are:

---

Simple: "A Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is simple if it is non-abelian and contains no non-trivial ideals."

Semisimple: "A Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple if it contains no non-trivial abelian ideals."

---

So, **a *simple* Lie algebra is one which is non-abelian and $I=\mathfrak{g}$ and $I=0$ are the only ideals.**

Here's my interpretation of the definition of semisimple: A semisimple Lie algebra can be abelian *or* non-abelian, and it is allowed to have non-trivial ideals as long as those non-trivial ideals are non-abelian, and the only ideals that are allowed to be abelian are $I=\mathfrak{g}$ and $I=0$ (though $I=\mathfrak{g}$ is clearly non-abelian if $\mathfrak{g}$ is non-abelian). Is this correct?

I'm rather confused about what it means for a Lie algebra to be semisimple. I know the definition that a semisimple Lie algebra is one that is a direct sum of simple Lie algebras, but **I'd like to find a statement that explains *semisimple* Lie algebras like the one I have in bold.** Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why did you [delete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3789469/understanding-the-definition-of-a-semisimple-lie-algebra-in-terms-of-ideals) this question and repeated it here again?

Comment: I had asked this question with confusing wording, so deleted it and worded it as above and tried to upload it again, but of course you can only ask a question once every 40 minutes.. I'm not sure if that's the reason it's deleted and repeated - I didn't intentionally delete and reupload an exact copy of the same question.

Comment: So we have two "definitions" of a semisimple Lie algebra.  The one as direct sum of simple ones is the easiest, right? Then we know exactly what the ideals are. Example: Take $\mathfrak{sl}(2)\oplus \mathfrak{sl}(2)$.

Comment: Maybe it helps clear some misunderstanding to say that, while the definition allows for a semisimple Lie algebra to be abelian, the only semisimple Lie algebra which actually is abelian is $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another equivalent definition is that $L$ is semisimple if and only if
$$
L=L_1\oplus \cdots \oplus L_n,
$$
where $L_1,\ldots ,L_n$ are simple ideals, i.e., ideals with the definition of "simple" in boldface.

For semisimple, this is what you said: $L$ is semisimple iff every abelian ideal is trivial.

Comment: Ok, so we only have the requirement that the abelian ideals must be trivial - can $L$ still be semisimple if it also contains non-abelian ideals that aren't trivial?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Take $\mathfrak{sl}(2)\oplus \mathfrak{sl}(2)$. It has the non-abelian ideal $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$, which is non-trivial.

Comment: Great, one more thing - isn't the statement "every simple Lie algebra is semisimple" true? How can this be the case if "simple" requires $L$ to be non-abelian, but "semisimple" requires the existence of abelian ideals?

Comment: Yes, every simple Lie algebra is semisimple. Indeed, every proper ideal of a simple Lie algebra is the zero algebra. And the zero ideal is an abelian ideal. Why are you saying that "semisimple requires the existence of abelian ideals"?

Comment: Ah! So despite the fact that a simple Lie algebra is non-abelian, it does in fact have one (and only one) abelian ideal (zero), and therefore is also semisimple?

Comment: This is correct.